# what this error denotes java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 1

Tags: jsp, jdbc

```
String sess_user = session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
out.println(sess_user);
try{  
      String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books";// books is the database  
      Connection connection = null;
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "bonnysingh");  

      Statement st = connection.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select email from signup where UserName = '" + sess_user +"'");
          while(rs.next()){
          userEmail = rs.getString(3);
          }
}
    catch(Exception ee){

        out.println(ee);
    }
out.println("Hello");
out.println(userEmail);
```

The output of userEmail is always null. I don't know what the problem here.but i think while(rs.next()) loop is not executing properly. Can anyone tell me whats the error?

Comment: Why do you even think that when you select a single column, that you should retrieve its value with `getString(3)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are only selecting a single column, yet you are trying to access the *third* column in your result.

Change `getString(3)` to `getString(1)` and you should be fine.

Comment: @DamanpreetSingh: I fail to see how your "*project*" has anything to do with this.